# http.client request method in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

When I run this code:

```
import http.client
hR = ["/index.html"]
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.python.org", 80)
conn.connect()
conn.request("GET", hR)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print (data)
conn.close()
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\files\fcon.py", line 5, in <module>
    conn.request("GET", hR)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\http\client.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\http\client.py", line 877, in putrequest
    if url.startswith('http'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Also, when I change the URL in line 3 to "http://python.org" I receive a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\files\fcon.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\http\client.py", line 721, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\socket.py", line 380, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first error message tells you that `hR` should not be a list, but a string, this would work:

```
import http.client
hR = "/index.html"
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.python.org", 80)
conn.connect()
conn.request("GET", hR)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print (data)
conn.close()
```

However you won't see any data, because `python.org` replies only with a http `301` respons redirecting to it's https page, which `http.client` does *not* automatically follow.

The second error you get because `http://www.python.org` is not a valid host name, `www.python.org` was correct here.

`http.client` is a rather low-level API, you should consider using `urllib.request` instead, or even betther the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) library.