# How to make httprequest in python

Tags: python, jython

I am having issue making rest call, it is throwing Exception during execution: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

```
def get_headers(request):
    #CSRF Protection
    response = request.get('crumbIssuer/api/json')
    if response.isSuccessful():
        crumb = JsonPathResult(response.response, 'crumb').get()
        return {'Jenkins-Crumb':crumb}

Server = 'https://jenkins.com'
username = user1
password = pwd

request = HttpRequest(Server, username, password)
headers = get_headers(request)
```

Comment: `request` is just a `unicode` string. you can't call get on that.

Comment: @JacobIRR --thanks for the reply, how do we make call to the other function ?

Comment: Perhaps you really want to use the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library instead?  You can also look at [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) too.  There is some [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples) code in the docs.

Comment: Here are gut examples:

1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763976/python-http-client-json-request-and-response-how
and 
2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671566/http-client-request-method-in-python-3?rq=1